# why compile non-static inner class will creation of hidden, package-visible methods on the parent class

Tags: java, inner-classes

IDEA said

> Reports non-static inner classes. Compilation of such classes causes the creation of hidden, package-visible methods on the parent class, which may compromise security.

So I want to know what this meaning.

demo code

```
public class TaiquShortV2 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    class TaiquData implements Serializable {//IDEA report TqiquData Class
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share code, which causes that warning?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557955/whats-the-penalty-for-synthetic-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to distinguish between the source code and the JVM level.

- At the source code level, the inner class `Inner` can access e.g. private fields of the enclosing class `Enclosing`.
- At the JVM level, there is no concept of an inner class: an inner class is just an independent class with a special name (typically containing a $ sign, e.g. `Enclosing$Inner`), located in the same package as the `Enclosing` class. Just like any other class, this `Enclosing$Inner` class can't access `Enclosing`'s private fields. To allow access to the private fields (as source code level demands), the compiler plays a trick: it secretly adds getters and setters to the fields, unter synthetic names (not the classical `getField()` and `setField()` names), and has the inner class use these access methods instead of a direct field access. And as both classes are in the same package, the access methods need to allow at least package visibility, and that's how they are created by the compiler.

So, these methods make it possible for any other class declared in the same package, to access private fields of the `Enclosing` class, breaking the normal encapsulation of private fields.

It's up to you to decide if that risk matters, as from within Java there are other possibilities to break the access rules. So, personally I've always happily created inner classes where appropriate from an architectural point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes (non static) are like any other attribute or method of  the class, they have access to other members. But static classes do not have this access.
So may be IDEA is warning you that if you do not need to access other members inside your nested class then it is better to make it static.

Please provide your code to better analyze it.

you can also look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-inner-class)

Comment: I add demo code